# How to distinguish first-order Feynman diagrams from the rest?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, feynman-diagrams, interactions

On what basis is it determined to what order the given Feynman diagram belongs? Does it depend on the number of interaction vertices? For example, two vertices are first order, four vertices are second order, and so on? It is clear that order zero is a diagram without vertices.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to tell the order of a Feynman diagram?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/175346/)

Comment: And what does this have to do with it? My question seems to be quite simple: how many vertices are there in first order diagrams?